# Question on One Shot Deviation (Game theory)

Tags: game-theory

Found this question in my practice set. This seems like a conceptually important question regarding the topic One shot deviation but I have absolutely no clue how to solve it..

[image: The question on one shot deviation]
[image: Continuation]

Would prefer an in-depth explanation if possible.

Edit: I was able to figure out (b) but I still need some help with (a)

Comment: Equilibrium refers to subgame perfect equilibrium? There is no one-shot deviation principle for Nas equilibrium.